# Append html to div not working on cordova iOS

Tags: ios, apache, cordova

I am using cordova 2.2.0 with Xcode 4.5.2. On one of my pages I have a select component and once a particular option is selected I want to display a table within a div. My html looks like this: `<div class="hero-unit" id="#facprog"></div>`

The javascript/jquery looks like this:

```
<pre><code>
$(function() { 
 $('#selFaculty').change(function() {
  var facultyName = $('#selFaculty').val();
  var progDetails = app.fillFacultyProgramme(facultyName);
  alert(progDetails);
  $('#facprog').append(progDetails);
 });
});
</code></pre>
```

Note that `#selFaculty` is the id of the select object. However, when the select option changes, everything in javascript executes except for the append. Nothing shows up in the div.  Is there a different way to add html element to a div in jquery under cordova 2.2.0 in iOS?
Thanks in advance,
José

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can refresh a div.

This is a good example:

```
<script> 
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
         $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('reload.php').fadeIn("slow");
     }, 20000);
 </script>
```

and now you need to put the div in the body section of your page

```
<div id="loaddiv"> 
</div>
```

from http://designgala.com/how-to-refresh-div-using-jquery/

and there is another example here:

[refresh div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427573/refresh-div-with-jquery)

The first example is useful when you need to load a script and refresh and the second one is useful when you need to make a change, e.g. append html and then refresh as in your case.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Actually the problem was in my selector. I wasn't picking the right object. I had to navigate through the DOM till I find the object I was looking for. Now it works fine