# How to display a webpage without reloading the entire DOM with a progress bar like youtube

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

How to display a webpage without reloading the entire DOM with a progress bar like youtube?

I tried Angular 4 and I likeview a page. If the visitor navigate through the site, that is it, the downside I see is the fact that the whole js and css need to be loaded to the client with a simple "Loading" simply to  fine, but if the visitor only consult a single page, this add a lot of bandwidth on both ends and wait/load time for the visitor.

In a perfect world, I would like a loading bar like youtube when the user switch page, and simply reload what changed (or it looked like it only reloaded what changed), for a smooth experience.

I started a little project with Hapi, Nunjucks and Polymer, and another one with Angular for comparison.

Does that even have a term? Since I don't really know the term, I feel like I don't even know what I'm talking about since I cannot research it, so I'm sorry in advance for my lack of knowledge.

**Things I want / I'm looking for:**

- Can use Hapi as backend (I'm used to it - or Koa)
- Independant ORM (I'm using RethinkDB, not a popular database choice)
- Reusable components
- Don't have to pack/load the whole JS (not like Angular)
- Have a way to show/monitor progress of loading
- Can be used with MDBootstrap (the most advanced material design bootstrap I've found)

EDIT: I noticed GitHub does the same thing.

Comment: I think this should help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799579/reload-a-div-without-reloading-the-whole-page

Comment: Thanks for that! Could I do that while monitoring the progress of the loading and change the address bar url?

Comment: It really sounds like you're looking for React.js. Is this question open to the idea of using a completely different frontend framework?

Comment: React? Argh then another framework to learn :P I would've prefer to stick to thing I know since I just started Angular 4 but I'll look into React - never really read about it (kind of forgot about it too)