# How do I refresh a div with AJAX without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, page-refresh

I am trying with this JS:

```
        function refresh () { 
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.torefreshdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

But this is loading the whole page inside the div, but i would like to refresh only the '.torefreshdiv'.
I thank everyone who helps me in advance.

Comment: Your `success` function *will* update only that class -- when you get valid data returned. Right now you have no data, and the `url` is the current page, so nothing is happening except refreshing the page.

Comment: use [load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) or parse out the element from data `$('.torefreshdiv').html($(data).find('.torefreshdiv').html());` etc

Comment: Is torefreshdiv a class or id for the div?

Comment: @RobMac since code shown is working then it is clearly a class

Comment: Create another resource for the content of the div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload a DIV without reloading the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799579/reload-a-div-without-reloading-the-whole-page)

Comment: @charlietfl that is the assumption, but what if it’s an ID and that’s the issue? Always good to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another resource for the content of the `<div>` to refresh (that can be another php script if using PHP, or the same script as the whole page but with some params...). Then:

```js
function refresh () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/div/to/refresh.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $('.torefreshdiv').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```